# Function Return Error in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have the following function: `prepare()` which returns `NSMUtableArray`. When I try, to return a `json` which is `NSMutableArray` object, I get the following error:

```
 'NSMutableArray' is not convertible to 'Void'
```

Function Source Code:

```
    func prepare() -> NSMutableArray {

    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
    let params = ["screen_name": "tikaDotMe"]
    var clientError : NSError?

    let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
        "GET", URL: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: params,
        error: &clientError)

    if request != nil {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
            (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                var jsonError : NSError?


                let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                    options: nil,
                    error: &jsonError) as NSMutableArray
          //Error: 'NSMutableArray' is not convertible to 'Void'
                return json



            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(clientError)")
    }
    return [""]
}
```

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: @user3581203 Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return json from a closure which is defined as returning a Void:

```
    (response, data, connectionError) -> Void
```

EDIT: As @Paulw11 mentions, you need to handle the data in your closure, you can't return it from your prepare function.

Comment: That won't work because the closure will be executed asynchronously, so the return value from prepare will be invalid. The OP needs to invoke an appropriate method to process the JSON from within the closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is it possible to make async:false?

Comment: It is better to code so that the asynchronous cals are handled correctly. Event-driven programming is an important paradigm in app development.

Comment: @Paulw11, good catch. I was looking at code I have that does something very similar. However, it is setting a property in a persistent data store, and not returning the data from the function itself.